# java executable jar file not working to another computer

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, executable-jar

I've built a executable JAR file and it executes fine on my PC (windows 10) which has Eclipse installed. but when I run this file from another PC with same Operating system. its not working(it can open the browser but not getting the website I mentioned). please Help me.

here is my code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class clAutomationWindow {

private JFrame frame;

private String DeriverFilePath;

private JTextField driverPath;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            try {
                clAutomationWindow window = new clAutomationWindow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public clAutomationWindow() {
    initialize();
}

 /**
  * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
     frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
     frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("AICT CL- Renew Post Automation ");
     lblNewLabel.setForeground(new Color(102, 102, 102));
     lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Centaur", Font.BOLD, 26));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(24, 11, 378, 43);
     frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

     JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Start Renew");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {




        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette",   DeriverFilePath);
        WebDriver browserDeriver = new FirefoxDriver();





            browserDeriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, SECONDS);

            browserDeriver.get("https://www.google.com");



        }});
    btnNewButton.setForeground(new Color(102, 102, 102));
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    btnNewButton.setBounds(23, 374, 120, 40);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    JButton button = new JButton("Show Driver");
     button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            JFileChooser Deriverpath = new JFileChooser();
            Deriverpath.showOpenDialog(null);
            File selectFile = Deriverpath.getSelectedFile();
            String placeOfFile= selectFile.getAbsolutePath();
            DeriverFilePath = placeOfFile.replace("\\","\\\\");
            driverPath.setText(placeOfFile);
        }
    });
    button.setForeground(new Color(102, 102, 102));
    button.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    button.setBounds(24, 182, 120, 40);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);

    driverPath = new JTextField();
    driverPath.setColumns(10);
    driverPath.setBounds(154, 187, 248, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(driverPath);
     frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 550);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you get any particular exception/error message?

Comment: I am using executable jar file to another pc. so I didn't get any error message. is there any way to get error message from executable jar file ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver not working with newer version of FireFox. 44.0.2 work fine.  I hope near future this problem will solved

Comment: Your statement is false and the problem sits in front of the PC. FirefoxDriver does work with current FF versions, you just need to upgrade the driver version. ;-)

Comment: But I am using geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64 and selenium-java-3.0.1 (1). which are latest. :-o

Comment: Then how do you explain that I can work with the very same driver version  0.14.0-win64 and FF 51.0.1 (32-bit)? Maybe you should be more specific than "does not work with current FF versions". What exactly does not work?

Comment: I don't have any explanation. I am looking for it. after see your comment. The code I gave above its not working. this is because I made this statement. after feedback from you i think problem maybe occur some where else. but where is it?  Thank you so much for your feed back :)

Comment: Maybe for me it works because I have Firefox 32-bit installed and you Firefox 64-bit? I never tried with a 64-bit FF. then maybe 32-bit FF is a good workaround for you if you want to test on the current version. Does nothing work or just some special calls? What kind of error do you see and where? As I said, "it does not work" is not a good problem description. Be more specific, please.

Comment: I quickly installed FF 51.0.1 64-bit and ran a few selenium tests, among them one operating on an Angular page with dynamic DOM changes. All of them work flawlessly. So probably your problem is not 32 vs 64 bit Firefox but something else.